# How to exit a while loop in host through client using sockets (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop

I'm still somewhat of a novice when it comes to coding so apologies if I don't explain my question thoroughly enough.

I am currently trying to create a system where I send a codeword to a raspberry pi (host) that will run a certain function depending on the codeword received from the client using sockets. I have that part of my code running fine and as expected. these functions are used to display patterns and whatnot on LED Lights so some are animated through the use of continuous while loops. When a function is called with a while loop, I am having difficulties finding a way to exit it through the client and not directly on the host. On the host, I can exit the loop with a keyboard interrupt but I am unsure of how to do it on the client side. when the host code is in a while loop, the client side will freeze up and not respond until the while loop is manually exited on the host side.

What I want to be able to do is send some kind of message from the client to the host to exit any while loop its currently in.

I've tried a couple methods but I'm currently a little too inexperienced to come up with a solution on my own.

Thank you for any help.

[Client Side Code. Each function sends a message to the raspberry pi (host)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzXcE.png)

[Connection setup for host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jso4j.png)

[Host checks message and goes to corresponding function that contains a continuous while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyM6H.png)

Comment: in your client code there is no while loop & host side you are using `break ` which is right  so can you explain  more  . small suggestion you convert `bytes` like `b''` simply with `decode` which will convert to string like `b'stop'.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I don't know the implementation of rendering methods / classes: Rainbow, gradient, gradred, but if they contain infinite loop, you will never be able to switch the pattern or stop the loop in dataTransfer function.